# Help with TikZ Squiggles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating a series of icons for a book with Ti*k*Z. I'm having trouble with one, however. The code below is how the icons appear: they are shadowed circles with a letter or number. However, I need one that looks like the picture below. Could anyone kindly tell me how to adapt my code below to reproduce this? Thank you!

[image: Squiggly line icon]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%---Tikz Icons Section

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{3cm}{3cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzstyle{every node} = [circle, circular drop shadow, fill=orange!80]
\node (a) at (0, 0) {!};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Band limited noise would do a reasonable job, but would have a hard time with the sharp v bottoms.  You could just use an image, unless you need to make each one slightly different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For instance like this. Control the width of the line using `line width`, control the number of samples using `samples` and control the envelope function of the noise using the constant before `rand`.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!80, circular drop shadow] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);

\draw[line width=1pt, color=white] plot [domain=-1.45:1.45, samples=64, smooth] (\x,{0.1*rand});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: However! For some reason this messes up my drop shadow that I had. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, I updated the code to include the shadow. I also changed the `scale` parameter to 1, which caused the wiggly line to break, so I had to change its parameters slightly as well. Now the shadow works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to reproduce this myself but failed. This is great work. Thanks so much for your assistance, @Augustin.